# BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA cannot update J_1IMTCHID table. Any workaround?

Tags: c#, sap-erp, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm connecting .NET application with SAP using SAP .NET Connector. It is working fine with `BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA`, but I need to update field `J_1IGRXREF` from table `J_1IMTCHID`, which does not exist in this BAPI. Is it possible to update this field using extension of this BAPI?

Or any other standard BAPI exists for updating this field while creating material?

Thanks in advance,
Vignesh

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no standard way to update this field via RFC (BAPI) in our system (Release 7.02).  If you are running an industry solution there is a slight change that there may be released functions to do this, but it's not very likely.

You will need an ABAP programmer to create an RFC to update this table.  ***Caution!!***  I'm also unable to find an internal released function module within SAP to update this table.  Function module `J_1IMTCHID_POST` is the only FM that updates this table in our system, and has ***not*** been released for customer use, and effectively does a direct table update of a SAP standard table, which is rarely advisable.

If you decide to go down this route (or have no other choice), it is very important that you ensure that any updates to this table honours SAP's intended use of the table, as any corruption of the data as a result of your change will not be supported under the SAP maintenance agreement.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.. i think its not possible to update this field using SAP .Net Connector ...

Answer (score -1):

Use BADI. It should help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: you should suggest possible BADI instead of generic advice